# Effect.SlideDown not working in a JS function declaration in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Why this is not working?

```
link_to_function "share", "slide-build(#{@idea.id.to_s})", :class => "share"
```

in my application.js

```
function share_build(aa) { Effect.SlideDown("s_" + aa); }
```

I used to have the javascript inside a helper in rails, and worked:

```
link_to_function ("share", nil , :class => "share") do |page|    
  page.visual_effect(:slide_down, "s_" + id.to_s, :duration => 0.5)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to quote the parameter

```
link_to_function "share", "slide-build('#{@idea.id.to_s}')", :class => "share"
```